# Can't connect to WiFi with WPA-EAP

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa, wpa2-eap

I'm trying to connect to a WiFi with WPA-EAP, but it always fails with error:

```
failure to add network: invalid message format
```

Full log from journalctl:

```
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  device (wlp5s0): Activation: starting connection 'eduroam' (1ed02f15-9f55-452c-9b1c-4b2670bb2eac)
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="1ed02f15-9f55-452c-9b1c-4b2670bb2eac" name="eduroam" pid=3216 uid=1000 result="success"
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  device (wlp5s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  device (wlp5s0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to 80:86:F2:1D:79:41 (preserve)
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  device (wlp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'eduroam' has security, but secrets are required.
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  device (wlp5s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  device (wlp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'eduroam' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'ssid' value 'eduroam'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'proto' value 'RSN'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'pairwise' value 'CCMP'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'group' value 'CCMP TKIP'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'password' value '<hidden>'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'eap' value 'PEAP'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'ca_cert' value '<mypath>/ca.pem'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'altsubject_match' value 'DNS:<mydomain.com>'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'identity' value '<myusername>'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'anonymous_identity' value ''
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
NetworkManager[668]: <warn>  sup-iface[0x5609a63bf980,wlp5s0]: assoc[0x5609a63c8f40]: failure to add network: invalid message format
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'supplicant-failed') [50 120 10]
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
NetworkManager[668]: <warn>  device (wlp5s0): Activation: failed for connection 'eduroam'
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  device (wlp5s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
NetworkManager[668]: <info>  device (wlp5s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 16:09:73:46:D9:3E (scanning)
kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing this line:

```
anonymous-identity=
```

from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/conname`.